# Is it possible to stop a login flow only for a particular community?

Tags: community, lightning-community, community-builder

We are using 4 communities, currently, all the communities using the login flow. I want to Stop it from triggering for a particular community. Is it possible?

Comment: When you say disable login, do you want it to be public or some other login flow?

Comment: Is making the community inactive an option? No one would be able to log in other than administrators.

Comment: No, I am not asking to inactivate the community. I am asking if we can STOP a login flow for a ivy community

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is detect which community you are in during the Flow and bypass the rest of the Flow if the community is the one in question.

There are a certain set of standard variables you can add to your Flow as input variables. If they exist with the proper name and are available as input, when the Login Flow is executed, they will be populated and you can use them to customize the behavior.

```
LoginFlow_LoginType
LoginFlow_IpAddress
LoginFlow_UserAgent
LoginFlow_Platform
LoginFlow_Application
LoginFlow_Community
LoginFlow_SessionLevel
LoginFlow_UserId
```

`LoginFlow_Community` is the one that will tell you which community the user is trying to log into.

From here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_login_flow_examples.htm